# How Do I Debug My Apps on an LG G4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I tried plugging in an LG G4 to my Ubuntu 16.04 development machine. I had already enabled USB debugging in Settings > Developer options on the G4. However, I did not get the USB debugging authorization dialog on the device, and `adb devices` does not show the device.

What do I need to do to get the G4 to be recognized?

Comment: @ColdFire: There are no drivers in Ubuntu.

Comment: didnt see that you self answered it , yeah for ubuntu it requires PTP to work , I own a LG G4 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference, compared to ordinary devices, is that the default MTP mode seems to break `adb`. PTP mode (for sending pictures) allows `adb` to work.

So, start by switching to PTP mode (via a notification when the device is plugged into your development machine) and see if `adb devices` now recognizes your device.

If not:

- Try adding `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"` to your `/etc/udev/rules.d/` file that you are using for `adb` rules (e.g., mine is `51-android.rules`), restart `udev`, then unplug and plug in the G4 again, then kill `adb` and restart it
- Try adding `0x1004` to `~/.android/adv_usb.ini`, then unplug and plug in the G4 again, then kill `adb` and restart it

Comment: had to install adb (wasnt included by default). tried your fix, but `adb devices` shows nothing and dmesg doesn't change, when plugging the phone in/out of the usb port. Phone just starts charging, doesn't show any usb popup (like on Android ≤5). Tried revoking usb privileges on the phone, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

try this :

$ sudo adb kill-server

$ adb start-server

unplug and plug Device its work for me